# Worksheet_Change, Intersect mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

Would appreciate some help with this.  When deleting the entire rows contents, or multiple lines, i am receiving a mismatch error on line: `If .Value = "CONFIRMED" Then`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expedia")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2:I1000")) Is Nothing Then

        With Target
            If .Value = "CONFIRMED" Then
                .Offset(0, 8).Value = "NEW"
                .Offset(0, 9).Value = Date
            ElseIf .Value = "" Then
                .Offset(0, 10).Value = "CHANGED"
                .Offset(0, 11).Value = Date
            ElseIf .Value = "INVALID" Then
                .Offset(0, 12).Value = "INVALID"
                .Offset(0, 13).Value = Date
            End If
        End With

    End If
```

Comment: It's freaking out because asking for the `.Value` of an entire row doesn't make sense. `Target` is a `Range` object so it can contain 1 or many cells. Perhaps if you only want this to fire for a single cell, you can add in something like `If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then`

Comment: Alternatively to limit it to one cell only as @JNevill proposed, you can loop through all of the affected cells (that intersect). See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining when `Target` is more than one cell.

You can secure that case by checking `Target.Count` at the beginning of a `Sub`:

```
If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that `Target` can also be a range of multiple cells. For example if you copy/paste some cells. Therefore you need to loop through all of the affected cells that intersect with your desired range `I2:I1000`, if you want to cover **all** of the pasted cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AffectedCells As Range 'get all cells that were canged and intersect with I2:I1000
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I2:I1000"))

    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events to prevent re-triggering this event when writing to cells
        On Error Goto ERR_HANDLING

        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedCells 'loop through all of the affected cells in I2:I1000
            With Cell 
                If .Value = "CONFIRMED" Then
                    .Offset(0, 8).Value = "NEW"
                    .Offset(0, 9).Value = Date
                ElseIf .Value = "" Then
                    .Offset(0, 10).Value = "CHANGED"
                    .Offset(0, 11).Value = Date
                ElseIf .Value = "INVALID" Then
                    .Offset(0, 12).Value = "INVALID"
                    .Offset(0, 13).Value = Date
                End If
            End With
        Next Cell
    End If

ERR_HANDLING: 'in the end or in case of error enable events or they stay disabled!
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I removed

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expedia")
```

because the variable `ws` was never used. If you want to refer to the worksheet the event (and `Target`) is in, then use `Me` like `Me.Range("I2:I1000")`

[image]

Comment: You should also check for multiple areas in the range: `For Each Area In AffectedCells.Areas.... For Each Cell in Area.Cells`.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers While this may be needed in several cases this is actually not necessary in this case. Test it. See the animation I added (it pastes in different areas). • But I added a `EnableEvents = False` which is a good idea.